# Getting information to pass between TableViewControllers once an event date has passed - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, datepicker, viewcontroller

I’m currrently working on an app that notifies a user when new music is released. The user types in the artist, album, release date (they select a date using a date picker) and it saves it to a list. On the date, they get a notification that this album comes out today.

Once the date passes, I would like it to come off the FreshListTableViewController and go onto the ReleasedTableViewController.

I appreciate the help.

Below is the code for the FreshReleaseTableViewController:

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData
 import UserNotifications

 class FreshReleaseTableViewController: UITableViewController{


    var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //create a new button
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none


    //let button1 = UIButton()
    //button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    //self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}


@objc func editAction() {
    let viewController = AddfreshreleaseViewController()
    navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
    do {
        freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return freshreleases.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0


    let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
    let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s '\nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

    if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        // Remove notification
        if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(freshrelease)
        freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not save \(error)")
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }

}



@available(iOS 11.0, *)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        let MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : UIViewController = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as UIViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        success(true)

    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue


    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

}
```

Below is the code for ReleasedTableViewController:

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData
 import UserNotifications

 class ReleasedTableViewController: UITableViewController{

var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //create a new button
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)



    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    //self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
    do {
        freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return freshreleases.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0


    let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
    let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s \nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

    if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        // Remove notification
        if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(freshrelease)
        freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not save \(error)")
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}



@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?



{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)
    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

 }
 */

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, need more clarification on your question.

Based on what you have mentioned:

> Once the date passes, I would like it to come off the
>   FreshListTableViewController and go onto the
>   ReleasedTableViewController.

Do you mean it's not currently updating? When I view the code, I don't see the part where it does as what you've mentioned. Meaning to say, I see that you are using `appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext` but not seeing the updates to check for the released album.

If what I understand is correct, you may want to include the release_date attribute in your CoreData and filter by current date in your CoreData.
If you are using a `.xcdatamodeld` file, add a release_date attribute inside that stores Date.

In your FreshReleaseTableViewController,

```
// ==== Filter by date
    let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(Date()) as! NSDate
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(your_date_attribute_name) > %@)", startOfToday)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
// ======
```

Vice versa for your ReleaseTableViewController,

```
// ==== Filter by date
let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(Date()) as! NSDate
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(your_date_attribute_name) < %@)", startOfToday)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
// ======
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling on how to get it to do that exactly. I don't have any updates to check for already released albums. So at the moment nothing happens when the date passes, it just continues to sit on that table, but I would like it to move to the other table. I'm looking for help on the whole process.

Comment: Hey @sckring, I've edited my answer to I think is what you are looking for? Anyway, I think the tag should be CoreData instead of TableVC. You should be fetching your CoreData with NSPredicate.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I'm assuming that code goes under the viewWillAppear function since that's where I've already defined fetchRequest? However, I'm getting this error now - Cannot assign value of type '[NSPredicate]' to type 'NSPredicate?'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I see. My bad. It's probably just looking for one nspredicate instead of an array. Remove the square brackets. Probably use predicate instead.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help. I'm currently getting the below error code:                                                                     2018-11-05 18:50:23.657088-0500 fresh release[12541:3087197] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "'release_date' > %@)"'

Comment: @sckring You should be using NSDate instead of Date.